# spring-boot war fails on startup

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, war, gretty

I am trying to make a web-service using spring-boot with gretty. It works well when calling `appStart` in gradle, but it would show error when calling `appStartWar`.

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.server.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at java_lang_Class$forName.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.SpringBootServerManager.startServer(SpringBootServerManager.groovy:46)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServerManager$startServer$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:70)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.this$2$run(Runner.groovy)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner$this$2$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:48)
Exception in thread "Thread-18" org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.javaexec(DefaultFileOperations.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.javaexec(AbstractProject.java:793)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$javaexec$8.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher.javaExec(DefaultLauncher.groovy:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:368)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure6.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy:216)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure6.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:504)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

It seems that it could not find the main class in war file, but the `com.example.server.Application` really exists in war with path `WEB-INF/classes/com/example/server`

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:1.1.8'
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.2.RELEASE'
    }
}

dependencies{

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.2.RELEASE'

    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

}

gretty {
    springBoot = true
    springBootVersion = '1.2.2.RELEASE'
    httpsEnabled = true
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder builder ) {
        return builder.sources( Application.class );
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String test() {
        return "success";
    }


}
```

Any help appreciated :)

---

Here's my project in Gitlab [link](https://gitlab.com/jason1122g/spring-boot-with-gretty/tree/master)

---

I've tried to deploy war to tomcat-7 directly, but it failed as well. So I think this is not a gretty problem.

**log**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5513)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer can not access a member of class com.example.server.Application with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:157)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it, could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @Opal thank you for help! I've added my example project link above.

Comment: Reproduced it, don't know the solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
```

class needs to be made *public*:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
```

In its current form it is package-protected and cannot be instantiated via reflection. (by default)

Comment: thanks, it works for tomcat now. but gretty `appStartWar` is still not working.

Comment: *If you still get the same error* (due to your problem with reflection), then you need to do a heavy cleanup. I do not know gretty, but try everything you can: clean / rebuild / redeploy. The only logical explanation for your problem to persist if the code change you made was not deployed properly, and it still using the old implementation.